# How can I declare a main attribute in ts file and use it in different ts files from different components

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have a main attribute `isSigned` in `app.component.ts` [app.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6tUT.png) and I want to use this attribute in `signIn.component.ts`[signIn.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeWHV.png) and `nav-bar.component.ts` [nav-bar.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf7qO.png) but i can't access to the main attribute `isSigned`

Comment: Could you edit your question with more details? Put an exemple of your code, as well.

Comment: Do you have a specific error message? Do you use @Input or Ngrx to share data between components?

Comment: I don't use `@Input` or `Ngrx` and this is the problem description : **Property 'isSign' does not exist on type 'typeof AppComponent'**